# IntelliJ Idea cannot run Kotlin files

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

Whenever I try to run Kotlin files clicking Alt+Shift+F10, it shows me Edit Configuration. everything is okay in it. Kotlin plugin is installed too, still the play button remains disabled.
Please help.

Comment: The code matters.

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of the run configuration dialog.